# How to silence Tensorflow Object Detection API warnings? WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <bound method SSDResNetV1FpnKeras

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Whenever I'm calling my detection function of the Tensorflow Object Detection API, I'm getting all this logging:

> WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <bound method SSDResNetV1FpnKerasFeatureExtractor.preprocess of <object_detection.models.ssd_resnet_v1_fpn_keras_feature_extractor.SSDResNet50V1FpnKerasFeatureExtractor object at 0x0000028E9E5AB6A0>> and will run it as-is.
> Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
> Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'
> To silence this warning, decorate the function with @tf.autograph.experimental.do_not_convert
> WARNING: AutoGraph could not transform <bound method SSDResNetV1FpnKerasFeatureExtractor.preprocess of <object_detection.models.ssd_resnet_v1_fpn_keras_feature_extractor.SSDResNet50V1FpnKerasFeatureExtractor object at 0x0000028E9E5AB6A0>> and will run it as-is.
> Please report this to the TensorFlow team. When filing the bug, set the verbosity to 10 (on Linux, `export AUTOGRAPH_VERBOSITY=10`) and attach the full output.
> Cause: module 'gast' has no attribute 'Index'

This is maybe 1/10th of it. How do I put a stop to this madness?

This is the function that causes it:

```
pipeline_config = r'..\pipeline.config'

configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)

model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=model)

_ = ckpt.restore('..\ckpt-1').expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect(image):
    image, shapes = model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections

detections = detect(input_tensor)
```

Comment: Have you tried to disable the log message using `warnings`? And is this log message only appear in your local machine? or colab etc. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37144)?

Comment: This is on my local machine, and I tried different things but not with `warnings`

Comment: [tf.autograph.set_verbosity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/autograph/set_verbosity) might help.  Looks like [others](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37144#issuecomment-600350256) have reported on this warning and TF says to ignore it (lol).

Comment: This autograph.set_verbosity should work. I've also gone through that report, here is another [one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41120#).